# I want to load hammer.js but after loading I want to disable it on based on some condition

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, hammer.js

I want to load hammer.js but after loading I want to disable it on based on some condition.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks,
Dinker.

Comment: Delete the `script` element if the required condition becomes true.

Comment: Thanks for replying.......

Correct me if I am wrong. We can use media queries for css but here I want to disable hammer.js plugin. Is there anyway to disable it using javascript?

Comment: Ohh Cool !! let me try :)

thanks,
Dinker

Comment: Are you using Modernizr? you can try that for conditional loading.

Comment: yes I am using modernizr but I do not want to go for conditional loading or even it would be better if I don't delete the script too. What exactly my requirement is I want to disable or deactivate this hammer plugin.

Comment: The issue is even if I delete the script element, functions in it will be already binded and Hammer.js will work fine !!  Any other suggestion would be helpfull ....